# Why doesn't the Unsigned trait automatically give e.g. the One trait in Rust?

Tags: types, rust, traits

I want to write generic functions of the form

```
fn my_function<T: num::Unsigned>(T: number) -> T
```

in order to use them for all unsigned integer types, so `u8`-`u128`.
However, often I want to do something like

```
let n = number + 1;
```

or

```
let mut n = number;
number -= 1;
```

in the function body. Now, everytime I use something like that, Rust tells me that the `std::ops::SubAssign`-trait, the `std::cmp::PartialOrd`-trait, etc. is not implemented for `T`.

Is there an easy way to specify that my number is only one of the types `u8`-`u128` and hence enjoys all of those traits? And why isn't this clear to the Rust compiler, i.e. what would be an example for an `Unsigned`-type that does not have the `PartialOrd`-trait?

Edit: To clarify: What I would love is a way to say "`T` has to have one of the types `u8`...`u128` (and maybe `BigUInt`)" and then have Rust to automatically see "since `T` is of one of those types, the following traits have to be implemented for `T`: `std::cmp::PartialOrd`, `std::ops::SubAssign`, ..."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the contrary, `T: Unsigned` *does* imply `T: One`. [`Unsigned`](https://docs.rs/num/0.4.0/num/trait.Unsigned.html) is a super trait over [`Num`](https://docs.rs/num/0.4.0/num/trait.Num.html) which is a super trait over `Zero`, `One`, and more:

```
pub trait Unsigned: Num { }
pub trait Num: Zero + One + NumOps<Self, Self> + PartialEq<Self> { ... }
```

The key thing to understand is that `1` is not the same thing as `T::one()`. This works for example:

```
use num::Unsigned; // 0.4.0

fn my_function<T: Unsigned>(number: T) -> T {
    number + T::one()
}
```

The `NumOps` trait means various arithmetic operators are defined, but only between `T`s. The literal `1` may not be a `T`, `T` could be something like [`BigUint`](https://docs.rs/num/0.4.0/num/struct.BigUint.html).

---

> What I would love is a way to say "`T` has to have one of the types `u8`...`u128` (and maybe `BigUInt`)" and then have Rust to automatically see "since `T` is of one of those types, the following traits have to be implemented for `T`: `std::cmp::PartialOrd`, `std::ops::SubAssign`, ..."

This is not how traits are designed to work. Traits can be implemented on foreign types, so even if `Unsigned` is only implemented for those types *now*, some other crate my implement it for their types which don't have all the same properties of `u8`...`u128`, etc.

Instead, you should *constrain* `T` to have the properties you need for the function to work. So you must be explicit.

Comment: I see...but why does the compiler then complain that `PartialEq` is not implemented, as it clearly is? And why doesn't `n += T::one()` (where `n: T`) work, whereas `n = n + T::one()` works?

Comment: I don't know what code you're talking about where `PartialEq` is an issue. The `NumOps` trait only covers the `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, and `%` operators, not `+=` and the like. You can use [`NumAssignOps`](https://docs.rs/num/0.4.0/num/traits/trait.NumAssignOps.html) as a shorthand for all of those.

Comment: For the `PartialEq`-trait: e.g. `while n > T::one() {...}` does not work. Also, I think I understand that there are different traits for operators and assign-operators, but my question is rather: is there a reason why the assign operators have an own trait instead of being just syntactic sugar for e.g. `n = n + T::one()`?

Comment: `PartialEq` (`==`, `!=`) is different from `PartialOrd` (`<`, `<=`, `>`, `>=`). And `+=` is not implemented in terms of `+` because that'd be very un-optimal for lots of types.

Comment: @JakobW. `<left> += <right>`  cannot be a shorthand for `<left> = <left> + <right>` because `<left>` can be a complicated expression such as `map.get(key).unwrap()[current_col].value` that you don't want to evaluate twice for efficiency and possible side effects. Also, for types such as bigints, you can actually implement in-place addition by modifying the existing value; in that case implementing `big += 1` as `big = big + 1` would unnecessarily create a new bigint and discard the old one.